# Install doorbell transformer on round junction box

Tags: light, junction-box, transformer, doorbell

Recently installed a Ring doorbell but realized that I need to hardwire a transformer to it. There's no existing transformer, so I'm thinking of wiring the transformer from the front door light (120v). My questions are:

- Is it safe to splice the transformer to the light?
- Should the transformer be inside or outside of the junction box? Attached is a picture of the junction box. I figure it has to be outside because the transformer and resister together can't fit in the box.
- Is it safe if the transformer is outside of the junction box but inside the cover of the light?

[image]

Comment: if possible, it would be better to run the LV wire through the wall where the Ring will be mounted and plug the transformer into an outlet on the other side of the wall.  A Ring power adapter cost about $30.  Doing it the way you described would have the LV wire expose from the light to the Ring doorbell, unless you are planning to run the LV wire back to the other side, and then back out to the ring.  Running straight through the wall behind the Ring, avoids all the issues and questions you have.

Comment: Do you have constant power at the light fixture, or is it switched?

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate No light on the porch, no business for people to come ringing. :-)

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate it's switched but i don't mind leaving it on to charge the ring doorbell.

Comment: @Programmer66 Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Can you post the make and model of the transformer you're using?

Answer (score 1):

If that light fixture has a roof or structure over it so it would be considered a dry location the transformer could be wired in that location. If no roof you may need a transformer rated for a damp location most are listed for a dry location only.